# Can't access mysql docker container from the host

Tags: mysql, iptables, docker

I have a debian server with docker `1.6.0` on it with a running official mysql container (https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/).

I use a fairly basic firewall configuration in which all ports are closed except SSH, HTTP and NTP (http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dFUcJWxy).

When I try to connect to my mysql database:

```
mysql -u root -h 172.17.0.3 -p
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.3' (110)
```

Port 3306 is filtered on it :

```
nmap -p 3306 172.17.0.3

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql
```

... and when I open port 3306 on the host i can access to the mysql server.

**How to access the mysql server container without opening port 3306 of the host machine ?**

**Further information than can help:**

The ansible task to launch the container :

```
- name: Mysql container
  docker:
    name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    state: started
    volumes:
    - /var/container_data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
    env:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my-root-password
```

`docker inspect mysql` -> pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uhXEhuXJ

`iptables -L` -> pastebin.com/raw.php?i=18fkgktF

`ifconfig` -> pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YJs2JnQx

If you need more information don't hesitate to ask me.

Best regards

Comment: Did you include a --link mysql flag on the container trying access the mysql container?

Comment: Yep I can access the mysql container from another container using `--link` but what I'm trying to do is be able to access from the host machine itself.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, opening port `3306` on the `docker0` interface solved my issue :

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -i docker0 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp -o docker0 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I think I'm running into a similar problem, as expressed by this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360687/connect-to-docker-mysql-container-from-localhost

Comment: Could you please elaborate or provide more details on the solution?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the real answer is to use the `--service-ports` option when starting the container using `docker-compose`:

`docker-compose run --service-ports db`

... as per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360687/connect-to-docker-mysql-container-from-localhost/32407507#32407507

Comment: Also, you can remove the `127.0.0.1` from the `docker-compose.yml` file if you use the `--service-ports` option

Answer (score 1):

Inside container in the mysqd.conf file:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

comment this:

```
bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

add this to below:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

And then restart the mysql service:

```
service mysql restart
```

Then start the container:

```
docker run  -p hostip:3306:3306 -it <image> bash
```

Replace the ***hostip*** with your host's IP address.

In the host, run:

```
mysql --host=hostip -u root -p
```

Comment: Fixed your format, spelling and grammar a bit. Added a few words to make it clearer also.

Comment: Can anyone point me to a gitbub or docker hub link that has a Dockerfile or (better yet) docker image I can use that has the appropriate bind-address of 0.0.0.0?