# Allow access to Docker container from localhost [IPTables]

Tags: linux, iptables

I need to allow access to my docker container with SQL from localhost, where my application is running. If I do IPtables default INPUT policy to ACCEPT, everything works. Can somebody help me with that one iptables rule?
Thank you

[Screenshot of my rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1DSd.png)

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-USER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 109.100.000.0/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2277 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 109.100.000.0/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 123 --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access mysql docker container from the host](https://serverfault.com/questions/688513/cant-access-mysql-docker-container-from-the-host)

Comment: Please do not post links to external site, and do not post screenshot, iptables rules are just text, so text output is preferred.

Comment: ok I posted in text form @JiriB

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect the exposed port to the host.

In your Dockerfile check the port 3306 is exposed:

```docker
EXPOSE 3306
```

then build the image as usual and run it while binding the internal port to the host

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306/tcp --rm <imageName>
```

then you can connect to the port 3306 in localhost.

You can find more information about the [mysql image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) and the [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) docs.